# What is the order of assignment/autoassociate and auto response with web-to-lead?

Tags: email-template, campaign, web2lead

I have a scenario, I need to auto associate new leads into campaigns, and send a customized email to them.

The auto-assignment and the auto-association both work perfect. However, the HTML template I use

[image]

Does not add the Campaign Name in the email sent to the new lead.

I believe it's something to do with : What's get completed first. And I fear that the Auto-association to the Campaign is done last.

Any other way I can send the customized template with the campaign name to a new registered lead?